# Is there anyway for Visual Studio to highlight any declared objects but are not assigned to an instance of an object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object, declaration

I am working on a Grasshopper3D (a graphical programming software that's an extension to Rhino) in Visual Studio. On compilation in Visual Studio, I get no errors. However, when I run the component, I am getting an error message that says:

[image]

Error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Is there anyway for Visual Studio to highlight any objects declared that are not set to an instance of an object?

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Well, it depends on the flow at run-time. You need to debug your code to find out WHY it is not set.

Comment: AFAIK it's not available. Run and see.

Comment: @Belogix For this particular issue - how would I use the VS Debugger to take a look at the issue? As ShellShock described below, it's an issue that can only be discovered at run-time.

Comment: Too much try/catch in the code, usually.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Because objects are created at run-time, there is no way at compile time to predict the future and tell whether a particular object will be instantiated when you run the program later. If there was a way, I could retire on my lottery winnings.

Edit: a useful tip using the VS Debugger, is to go to the Debug, Exceptions menu, and tick the option for Common Language Runtime Exceptions, Thrown. Now, when any CLR exception is thrown (including the NullReferenceException you are seeing), the debugger will break into the code where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Are you sure you can't predict the future :-P?